# Linux: How to receive warning email from a server when not much hard drive space left?

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, centos6.4

I am building a new CentOS 6.4 server.

I was wondering if there is a way I can receive a warning email when the use of any partition exceeds 80% in the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may aks this on UL - not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always create a bash script & then have it email you:

```
usage=$(df | awk '{print $1,$5}' | tail -n +2 | tr -d '%');
echo "$usage" | while read FS PERCENT; do [ "$PERCENT" -ge "80" ] && echo "$FS has used ${PERCENT}% Disk Space"; done;
```

Obviously instead of the `&& echo "$FS has used ${PERCENT}% Disk Space"` you would send the warning email.

Comment: You should also check INODE usage - and it should be generic as well. So a script will get more complex than this.

Answer (score 2):

Install a monitoring service like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/).

Answer (score 1):

THer are tons of products - commercial and open source - that can be used to track resource utilization in a server farm. THere is scripting with a cron job running every x minutes that a professional admin would put up in 5 minutes or less to check that and send an email when needed. So, that are two distinct ways - get a proper management suite, or do what admins do and write a script.

We do not do product recommendations here (as per FAQ) and - we assume people are not admin beginners (As per rules of this site).